# how to use genderize package for python with big datasets?

Tags: python, api, package

I am using [genderize package for python](https://github.com/SteelPangolin/genderize) to infer the gender of names. I have a csv file of more than 7 thousands of names. In my code, the csv file is passed into the genderize function. I want the function to return the gender for all of the names in the file, however, it only returns the gender of the first 10 names in the csv file. Is there anyway to infer the gender of names in a file by calling the function once? Here is my code:

```
from genderize import Genderize
import csv
with open('.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)
print(Genderize().get(your_list))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is limited to a maximum of 10 names per request. Split your list and do multiple calls. And read the manual: https://genderize.io/